# OPENJSON in SQL server returning values stored as "" into zeros

Tags: .net, json, sql-server

The JSON I need to parse:

```
{
"OutPut":[
    {"Task":"Pr","Min":"","Max":""},
    {"Task":"ED","Min":"0","Max":""},
    {"Task":"Dr","Min":"0","Max":"0"},
    {"Task":"Pt","Min":"","Max":"0"},
    {"Task":"Pr","Min":"1","Max":"0"}
]
}
```

This is where I called `OPENJSON()`:

```
INSERT INTO RoleMinMaxTemp  
    SELECT *  FROM OPENJSON(@FldKPRoleRequirementsList,'$.OutPut')    
        WITH (  
       Role nvarchar(1000) '$.Role',  
       Min INT '$.Min',  
       Max INT '$.Max'  
         )  
    END
```

When displayed the `""` is replaced by `0`. How can I avoid that?

Comment: What is the expected output when the value is `""`?

Comment: it should be "" or null.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#option-2---openjson-output-with-an-explicit-structure) - `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema converts the values to the specified type.

> When you specify a schema for the results by using the WITH clause of
>   the OPENJSON function, the function returns a table with only the
>   columns that you define in the WITH clause. In the optional WITH
>   clause, you specify a set of output columns, their types, and the
>   paths of the JSON source properties for each output value. OPENJSON
>   iterates through the array of JSON objects, reads the value on the
>   specified path for each column, and converts the value to the
>   specified type.

One possible solution here is the following statement, which defines `Min` and `Max` columns as `nvarchar` columns:

```
DECLARE @FldKPRoleRequirementsList nvarchar(max) = N'
{
"OutPut":[
    {"Task":"Pr","Min":"","Max":""},
    {"Task":"ED","Min":"0","Max":""},
    {"Task":"Dr","Min":"0","Max":"0"},
    {"Task":"Pt","Min":"","Max":"0"},
    {"Task":"Pr","Min":"1","Max":"0"}
]
} 
'

SELECT 
   [Task],
   TRY_CONVERT(int, NULLIF([Min], '')) AS [Min],
   TRY_CONVERT(int, NULLIF([Max], '')) AS [Max]
FROM OPENJSON(@FldKPRoleRequirementsList, '$.OutPut') WITH (  
   [Task] nvarchar(1000) '$.Task',  
   [Min] nvarchar(1) '$.Min',  
   [Max] nvarchar(1) '$.Max'  
)
```

Result:

```
---------------
Task    Min Max
---------------
Pr      
ED      0   
Dr      0   0
Pt          0
Pr      1   0
```